# How can I install ubuntu from the ISO in Windows?

Tags: installation, boot, usb-drive, iso

I don't have a usb stick or discs available to boot from, so is there anyway I can use the ISO image to install from within windows?

I tried using the Windows installer but the download keeps failing and takes ~5 hours.. So I downloaded the iso via torrent in about 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

If you mount the ISO using something like [Daemon Tools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/products/dtLite), it *should* have wubi.exe autostart immediately and install using the mounted drive.

If this has changed in recent times, when you run the windows installer, you should be able to choose either the iso file or the mounted iso drive as the source.

Edit:

Yes you are right, there is no manual source change option. You need do the below

> **How can I use a manually downloaded ISO?**
>
> You need to download the DESKTOP CD ISO of the appropriate version. Place the ISO in the same folder where you have wubi.exe and then run Wubi. For example, Wubi 11.10 requires the 11.10 DESKTOP ISO, available here.
>
> Note that you need a DESKTOP CD ISO. A DVD ISO may not work (except for Edubuntu). Alternate ISO files are not supported.

[Source : WubiGuide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_can_I_use_a_manually_downloaded_ISO.3F)

Good Luck!

Comment: I'll give mounting it a try, thanks. I didn't see an option to change the source in the windows installer, I already looked for it but I'll check again

Comment: @themcs pls check my edit

Comment: Turns out I downloaded the server version by mistake, so I'm waiting on the desktop version to download now.     However, I'm not sure if it's a CD iso or a DVD iso. The file size is 763mb so it would seem it's slightly too big for a CD.

         ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent is the torrent I'm downloading from [Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads)

Comment: @themcs Hmm dunno about that. Not sure if wubi.exe has been removed from ISOs lately, otherwise that was the method I used to use

Comment: installation by mounting ISO, and executing wubi.exe from inside ISO is blocked in 12.10 due to bugs. Follow as wubiguide says, you will be good to go.

Comment: The ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent will give you a DVD iso which might not work as mentioned above. I think spending the same time to find a solution to using first a live DVD or, as a second choice, live USB can yield better results as wubi.exe seems to be a so to speak "third-class" solution in comparison to others in view of complaints aired there.